# if empty query show messages in php

Tags: php, pdo

I need little help with my code. 
I want to show message when table is empty.

My code is

```
function category()
{
    global $config,$db,$lang;
    $result = "SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY id";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($result);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $tpl=parse_tpl('category.php');
        $tpl=str_replace("{_HTTP_SERVER_}",$config['http_server'],$tpl);
        $tpl=str_replace("{cat_id}",$row['id'],$tpl);
        $tpl=str_replace("{cat_title}",kill_tags($row['name']),$tpl);
        echo $tpl;
    }
    if(empty($row)) echo $lang['category_not'];
}
```

When no records in table show this message

```
 $lang['category_not']
```

I tried with `if(empty($row))` , `if (!$row)` and `if($row == o)` but didn't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your code as following way:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
{
   echo "nothing found message";
}
else
{

  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
  {
    // code for loop
  }
}// else ends here
```

Comment: Infinite loop, whoopee!

Comment: Skipping the first result row, whoopee!

Comment: Well, finally something... :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem solved with $stmt->rowCount() == 0

Comment: @MartinKalco Please upvote and approve my answer as solution. Because I have gotten negative vote from some unknown users without any reason except than deceze.

Comment: @MartinKalco Thank you!